# How would I set Google Forms/Sheets to auto print new form responses?

Tags: javascript, forms, printing, google-sheets, cloud

I currently have a google form for item requests that are made by users. It updates a google sheet with all of the pertinent information.

I'm looking for a way to automatically print the form submitted by users through the google Cloud Print services: Can they be printed as they are submitted?

Do I need a custom app/script to make this possible or can it be done within google sheets (something like `=IF(Blah, PrintTo(cellRange, somePrinter)`)?

I have very little programming experience but any help/direction is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tutorial that appears to be setting up a workflow very similar to yours with Google Cloud Print Service:

https://digitalinspiration.com/print-documents-google-cloud-print-5924

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for this! Since its for work purposes we couldn't go through with this app/service since it needed access to modify/create/and delete all emails and google drive entries, but immediately after reading into it I found Zapier which did the same thing for enterprise for free (also more trusted and less access needed). Thanks again Robert!